# Parentheses notation in number theory

Tags: number-theory, notation

I'm looking at the following problem.

> $p$ is a prime number. For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ab^2 \equiv c^2$ (mod $p$). If $(\frac{a}{p}) = -1$, then $b^2 \equiv c^2 $(mod $p^2$).

The solution says that $p$ does not divide $a$ because $(\frac{a}{p}) = -1$. What is $()$ suppose to mean?

Thank you.

Comment: It is the Legendre symbol. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol $$\left(\frac ap\right)=\begin{cases}0&p\mid a\\1&p\not\mid a\land \exists x: x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}\\-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: If you are looking on such a problem you could also look into a text on such a topic. Then the necessary definitions are given there.

Comment: Indeed, if this is a homework exercise, then the notation would’ve been defined in the material you’re assumed to have studied before the problem set.

Answer (score 1):

It’s the Legendre symbol.  When it’s $-1$, the top number is not a quadratic residue (perfect square) modulo the lower number.